# Updating Field in DataTable when TextBox is updated

Tags: c#, datatable, passwords, password-protection, in-memory

I have the need to update a field in a DataTable in C# app - when the user changes the data.

The DataTable is an in-memory DataTable - I save and load any data into it to an XML file (writeXML method), so there is no underlying database.
I am using this to hold some information about logins, and thus I have a password field that I want to encrypt. This is important as when I run the save to XML, it would otherwise write the password out un-encrypted.

I am looking at doing this two different ways and would appreciate some feedback.

1. Load from XML, then decrypt all password values in each row and encrypt them just before the Save to XML. I could use something like:

   ```
   foreach (DataRow row in tmp.Rows)
   {
       row["PW"] = EncryptIt(row["PW"].ToString());
   }
   ```

   However, this seems somewhat insecure. It would give me a DataTable in memory that has the passwords decrypted. But I suppose no different than decrypting the passwords one at a time when used...
2. Keep the passwords in the in-memory DataTable encrypted.  But when the user uses a screen to edit the records, I could encrypt the value entered in the TextBox after the user has entered it. I could then also decrypt the value from the DataTable whenever I need to use it. This would keep the passwords encrypted in the DataTable, but I would have to decrypt them when I need to use them so I am not sure it is really all that more secure than the easier method above.

What are you thoughts on method 1 vs 2 above?

Method #2 above also introduces some additional questions about how best to encrypt the data - by this I mean using what event?

I have been playing with `EditValueChanged` and `TextChanged`, but they both seem to fire for every character that is changed. I would also have to account for various cases such as leaving the field, and not leaving the field in the case where the user changes the field and then just hits the Save button without leaving the field.

How would you go about updating the underlying DataTable field when the user changes a TextBox that is databound to that field (through a binding source)?

I am beginning to think option one would be easier to implement and no worse off in terms of security. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but if you're new to storing passwords you should definitely give [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6068/is-it-possible-to-securely-store-passwords-using-reversible-encryption) and [this](http://security.blogoverflow.com/2013/09/about-secure-password-hashing/) a read.

Answer (score 0):

Of the 2 methods you suggest I'd go for the second if you're concerned about clear-text in memory.
You can also consider hashing the passwords in the database. Hashing is kind of a one-way encryption where you always compare the "encrypted" result and won't be able to retrieve the original password.

There is a good article [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38951/How-To-Hash-Data-Using-MD-and-SHA) about hashing

Ad for the second part, when the user clicks the save button, the edit field loses focus first, so if you subscribe to the textbox's `leave` event you should be safe.

Comment: Hello Henrik,  thank you for the quick reply.  You are correct about the Leave event... Now that I think about it - it is obvious :)

Answer (score 0):

I was going to comment, but I figured it would be better to reply since I'm sending some sample code.

A far better method of handling password storage is to generate a salt, then use that to hash the password, then store the salt and hashed pass in the database.  When a user logs in, you get the salt, hash their input with it, then compare to the hash in the database.

```
    public static string CreateSalt(int size)
    {
        // Generate a cryptographic random number using the cryptographic
        // service provider
        RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] buff = new byte[size];
        rng.GetBytes(buff);
        // Return a Base64 string representation of the random number
        return Convert.ToBase64String(buff);
    }

    public static string CreatePasswordHash(string pwd, string salt)
    {
        string saltAndPwd = String.Concat(pwd, salt);
        string hashedPwd =
              FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(
                                                   saltAndPwd, "SHA1");
        hashedPwd = String.Concat(hashedPwd, salt);
        return hashedPwd;
    }
```

Those are the two helpers you'll need.
To create the hashed password (for a new user), you do something like this:

```
var salt = CreateSalt(24);
var passHash = CreatePasswordHash(password, salt);
```

Again, store the salt and hashed pass in the database.

When checking the login, ask the database for the salt and the hashed pass.
Hash the password like before, then compare to the hashed pass.

Better yet, even more secure, create a stored procedure in the database that returns if the hashed pass is the same as the one in the table - then the hashed pass is never even downloaded to the client at all, only the salt.

It should be noted though, according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.hashpasswordforstoringinconfigfile(v=vs.110).aspx the `FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile` method is obsolete, and you should check out http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=252463 however, I have no sample code for you there (that I can think of...).  Of course, if you are using a desktop / windows forms application, that won't help you, but the main point:

Hash password using salt.
Never decrypt the stored password.